# búsqueda precisa

Tags: python

Tengo un archivo con mucha información acerca de los equipos con los que se trabajan en la empresa, si busco coincidencias con el programa me aparecen las mismas **n** cantidad de veces que existan en el archivo

mi jefe exige realizar una búsqueda precisa en el **archivo** desde dónde sale la ip hasta donde indica comando aceptado.

ejemplo: en *objetivo.txt* hay los resultados de mas de 300 dispositivos y se necesita extraer solo uno de ellos con un rango desde

```
midireccion show cdp neighbors detail:C#  
..
..
```

hasta  `comando aceptado`

`objetivo.txt` contiene:

```
02/18/19 10:32:04 10.1.0.21 show cdp neighbors detail:C#
-------------------------
Device ID: xxxxx
Entry address(es): 
  IP address: xxx
Platform: cisco WS-C2940-8TF-S,  Capabilities: Switch IGMP 
Interface: GigabitEthernet0/12,  Port ID (outgoing port): FastEthernet0/8
Holdtime : 155 sec
.
.
.
.
Management address(es): 
  IP address: 170.179.108.11
-------------------------
comando aceptado
```

hay un archivo que contiene esos datos de casi 300 dispositivos y es delimitar desde donde se indica la direccion  **10.1.0.21 show cdp neighbors detail:C#** hasta **comando aceptado**

el código que busca en el archivo es:

```
#archivovv5.insert("1.0", line) envia la información a un scrolledtext de tkinter y muestra el resultado
#se reciben las palabras que coinciden y se almacenan en palabra. palabra2...
def busqueda():
    f=open("objetivo.txt",'r')

    palabra=busquedas.get()
    palabra2=busquedass.get()
    palabra3=busquedassi.get()
    lines = f.readlines()

    for line in lines:
        if palabra in line:
            if palabra !="":
                archivovv5.insert("1.0", line)

        if palabra2 in line:
            if palabra2 !="":
                archivovv5.insert("1.0", line)

        if palabra3 in line:
            if palabra3 !="":
                archivovv5.insert("1.0", line)
```

si busco: `Holdtime` me trae

```
Holdtime : 159 sec
Holdtime : 142 sec
Holdtime : 161 sec
Holdtime : 172 sec
Holdtime : 166 sec
Holdtime : 176 sec
Holdtime : 135 sec
Holdtime : 168 sec
.
.
.
.
.
Holdtime : 150 sec
```

y debería de estar dentro de

```
midireccion show cdp neighbors detail:C#
...
...
Holdtime : 135 sec
...
comando aceptado
```

---

oye @metamax, entiendo tu sintaxis y todo, pero no quiere guardar nada en el archivo, he aqui otro modo al que lo implemento ya que ni a la tuya ni a la mia quiere escribir...

nota: si crea el **ficheroSalida** pero vacío y si coloco los cuadros de texto vacíos si escribe en el archivo pero no lo que necesitamos

```
#estas son variables globales que almacenan los datos que el usuario escribe en un tkinter Entry
busquedas=StringVar()
busquedass=StringVar()

#aqui la función actualizada trayendo los datos que necesito de los TK.Entry
def buscar():
cont = 0
direccion=busquedas.get()
otro=busquedas.get()
ficheroEntrada = open("objetivo.txt", "r")
ficheroSalida = open("resultado.txt", "w")
ficheroEntrada.readlines()

busqueda = direccion +" "+ otro # El "\n" es porque cada linea tiene un salto y si no lo especificas no son iguales a la cadena que estas buscando
for linea in ficheroEntrada:
    if linea == busqueda:
        cont = 1
    if linea == "comando aceptado\n":
        cont = 0
    if cont == 1:
        ficheroSalida.write(linea)
ficheroEntrada.close()
ficheroSalida.close()


# aqui los cuadros de texto, la pantalla donde pertenecen  y el botón
buscare=Entry(principal5, textvariable=busquedas)
buscare.place(x=200, y=300, width=150)
buscarr=Entry(principal5, textvariable=busquedass)
buscarr.place(x=200, y=350, width=150)
botonb=Button(principal5, text="Buscar Coincidencias", command=buscar).place(x=200, y=450)
```

he intentado jugar con las igualaciones y condicionales pero no resulta

Comment: Francisco, he editado tu pregunta para que los ejemplos de cómo es la entrada y la salida esperada se vean en el formato correcto, para que sea más fácil leerlo y ayudarte. Revisa por favor si efectivamente era así como debe verse

Answer (score 0):

Mira hace un tiempo me toco hacer algo parecido asi que te paso el codigo modificado segun tu caso, es un poco rudimentario pero funciona:

```
def buscar(direccion):
    cont = 0
    ficheroEntrada = open("archivoTexto.txt", "r")
    ficheroSalida = open("resultado.txt", "w")

    busqueda = direccion + " show cdp neighbors detail:C#\n" # El "\n" es porque cada linea tiene un salto y si no lo especificas no son iguales a la cadena que estas buscando
    for linea in ficheroEntrada:
        if linea == busqueda:
            cont = 1
        if linea == "comando aceptado\n":
            cont = 0
        if cont == 1:
            ficheroSalida.write(linea)
    ficheroEntrada.close()
    ficheroSalida.close()


buscar("02/18/19 10:32:04 10.1.0.21")
```

El archivo "archivoTexto.txt" lo puse de esta forma:

```
basura1
basura2
basura3
02/18/19 10:32:04 10.1.0.21 show cdp neighbors detail:C#

Device ID: xxxxx

Entry address(es):

IP address: xxx

Platform: cisco WS-C2940-8TF-S, Capabilities: Switch IGMP

Interface: GigabitEthernet0/12, Port ID (outgoing port): FastEthernet0/8

Holdtime : 155 sec

. . . .

Management address(es):

IP address: 170.179.108.11

comando aceptado
basura4
basura5
basura6
```